# Запятая!!! Придаточное?

Tags: пунктуация

И толпы инсультников, инфарктников и гипертоников, восславив это событие, хлынули туда лечить, кто, что может. Запятая перед "что может"? верно?

Answer (score 1):

"Кто что может" - это устойчивый оборот, его обособление зависит от структуры предложения.

Можно предложить  необособленный вариант (при отсутствии паузы): И толпы инсультников, инфарктников и гипертоников, восславив это событие, хлынули туда лечить **кто что может**.

А вообще говоря, оборот может обособляться тире как присоединительная конструкция, может выделяться запятыми или не обособляться в роли дополнения, отнесенного к сказуемому:

(1) Из Бахты тоже привозили ― ***кто что может***. [Михаил Тарковский. Жизнь и книга // «Октябрь», 2002]

(2) Сохраним, спрячем, ***кто что может***, а придут наши, опять снесем сюда. [Михаил Бубеннов. Белая береза / части 1-2 (1942-1952)]

(2)А ну по домам и ― сюда: тащите **кто что может.** [Гавриил Троепольский. Белый Бим черное ухо (1971)]

Comment: Ведь вопрос был о запятой перед "что". Она неуместна в любом случае, не так ли?

Comment: Запятая неуместна, так как не соответствует структуре предложения "кто что может", где ЧТО - в роли дополнения, КТО - в роли подлежащего. Сравнить: тащите то, что вы можете.